# YouTube Video autoplay

Tags: post-editor, youtube

I am using a YouTube embed on my site. To make it autoplay I have added `?autoplay=1` to the embed too. The code when added to the page/post editor, is showing the video with autoplay. But on the front end, the video is not playing automatically.

Is there any possible reason for that?

Here is the code I am using:

```
<iframe width="460" height="220" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rUWxSEwctFU?autoplay=1&controls=0&loop=1&playlist=rUWxSEwctFU&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

**Update:** I think it is working on Chrome, but not in Firefox